# positioning kendo right click menu

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, contextmenu, positioning

I have right click menu (contentmenu) but it show only in one static position (int he bottom). Can you help me? I use this code:

```
<ul class ="k-column-menu" id="contextmenu" style=" display:none; position: absolute; background-color:white; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;" >
<li>Genres</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
```

and this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).bind('contextmenu', function (event){
            $("#contextmenu").kendoMenu({ position: "relative", orientation: "vertical" }).show();
         event.preventDefault();
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function () {
                $("#contextmenu").hide();
        });

    });
```

I solved this issue like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).bind('contextmenu', function (event){
            $("#contextmenu").css({ "top": event.pageY + "px", "left": event.pageX + "px" }).kendoMenu({orientation: "vertical"}).show();
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function () {
                $("#contextmenu").hide();
        });

    });
```

Iwant to ask another question. How can i make this menu to show only when right clicking on the columns header and nowhere else on the page or table

Comment: Can you provide a fiddler link? It would be easy to solve your question.

Comment: I have done the menu. But is shows on every right click in the browser. I want this menu to be shown only when right clicking on the column header(name) not in the cell or anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the `<th>` tag when you `bind` the `click event`.

*Updated link:*

Here is **[a simple example.!](http://jsfiddle.net/VB5um/1/)**

*Another Update*

and here is **[another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1283/)** according your requirement you  only need to change

this:

```
$(document).bind('contextmenu', function (event){
     $("#contextmenu").kendoMenu({ position: "relative", orientation: "vertical"}).show();
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

to this:

```
$(".k-header").bind('contextmenu', function (event){
     $("#contextmenu").kendoMenu({ position: "relative", orientation: "vertical"}).show();
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i made this changes:
 $(document).ready(function() {
            
                $("#Grid").bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
                    $("#contextmenu").css({ "top": event.pageY + "px", "left": event.pageX + "px" }).kendoMenu({ orientation: "vertical" }).show();
                    event.preventDefault();
                });

                $(document).bind('click', function() {
                    $("#contextmenu").hide();
                });
            });

But it allowes the menu in the table also. As i said i want it just on the columns header.

Comment: I have one more question. Do you know how to make menu item(on this particular menu) when i can resize my column width?

Comment: On this right click menu, i need to have a textbox where when it is first open it need to have the current column size(in px) and then i can change the size and autamatically resize the column width